# prove the flow $f(χ) $ across any cut is equal to the flow value of the network $|f|$

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I have one question please about proving that the flow $f(χ) $ across any cut is equal to the flow value of the network $|f|$. Now, the flow of the cut is the difference between flow of forward edges (start if $V_s$ and ends in $V_t$), where $s$ and $t$ are source and sink vertices and $χ$ is the cut of the vertices into  $V_s$ and $V_t$.

If we take total flow of a cut, which is defined as the flow $F$ as follows,

$$F = \sum_{v\in V_s}\left(\sum_{e\in E^{+}(v)}^{}(f(e))- \sum_{e\in E^{-}(v)}^{}(f(e))\right)$$

**Case 1**: for all vertices other than the source, we will have by conservation law that, for all vertices $v \in V_s$ other than source $s$,

$$F = \sum_{v\in V_s}\left(\sum_{e\in E^{+}(v)}^{}(f(e))- \sum_{e\in E^{-}(v)}^{}(f(e))= 0\right) = |f| $$

where $|f|$ is the flow of a network as the total flow from the source.

**Case 2**: On the other hand, for each edge e that is not a forward or a backward edge of
cut χ, the sum F contains both the term $f(e)$ and the term $−f(e)$, which cancel each other, or neither the term $f(e)$ nor the term $−f(e)$. Thus, $F = f(χ)$, where $f(χ)$ is the flow a cross the cut that is the difference between flow of forward edges minus flow of backward edges.

**Problem**: can you please clarify case 2 as I don't get it clearly?

Comment: Are you studying Ford-Fulkerson algorithm ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thank you. Maximum flow in general, which has FF algorithm. I saw this theorem above, I understand case 1, but just want to know more about case 2 please